# Convert Datatable to nested list/object using C#

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have a datatable as this.  [image] and data model as

```
public class Details
    {

        public String Id { get; set; }
        public String Type { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String Terms { get; set; }
        public List<FAQ> Faqs { get; set; }
    }

    public class FAQ
    {
        public string Question { get; set; }
        public string Answer { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to convert it to a list type of details like 
`List<Details> detatilsList;` I tried like this but the rows are repeating. 
If i remove Details than I get distinct result but cant convert it to Details type due to anonymous cast exception

```
 var details = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x =>
                new Details //removing this detail gives distinct record as expected. But can not cast
                {
                    ID= x.Field<decimal>("ID"),
                    NAME = x.Field<string>("NAME"),
                    TYPE = x.Field<string>("TYPE"),
                    TERMS = x.Field<string>("TERMS")
                })
            .Select(x =>
                new
                {
                    x.Key.ID,
                    x.Key.NAME,
                    x.Key.TYPE,
                    x.Key.TERMS,
                    Faqs =
                    x.Select(
                        s => new Faq {Question = s.Field<string>("QUESTION"), Answer = s.Field<string>("ANSWER")})

                }).ToList();
```

How can i fix it and convert it to List of Details

Comment: You need to `Select` your `Details`, and `GroupBy` the correct grouping elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group By by anonymous object for multiple keys then select the required columns from `DataTable`

The below code first groups the data using `ID` , `Name`, `Type` and `Terms` and later in Select clause, creates new `Details` object.

```
 var details = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x =>
            new
            {
                ID= x.Field<decimal>("ID"),
                NAME = x.Field<string>("NAME"),
                TYPE = x.Field<string>("TYPE"),
                TERMS = x.Field<string>("TERMS")
            })
        .Select(x =>
            new Details
            {
                x.Key.ID,
                x.Key.NAME,
                x.Key.TYPE,
                x.Key.TERMS,
                Faqs =
                x.Select(
                    s => new Faq {Question = s.Field<string>("QUESTION"), Answer = s.Field<string>("ANSWER")}).ToList()
            }).ToList();
```

Another point, if `Id` itself is unique then you don't need to group by multiple columns, you can group by ID only.

Comment: I also tried like this but it says Cannot implicitly convert type system.collection.generic to system.generic.list<FAQ> on this line
x.Select(
                    s => new Faq {Question = s.Field<string>("QUESTION"), Answer = s.Field<string>("ANSWER")})

Comment: Added `ToList` to select FAQs. With the update the details with FAQ will be populated